# RoR - how do I get admin to show single users documents on index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have **users#show** page as an admin, which lists all users as below:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="row row-cols-3">
    <div class="col-2">
      <%= image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize_to_fill: [100, 100]), style: "border-radius: 50%;" %><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>user name: <%= user.first_name %> <%= user.last_name %></p>
      <p>user email: <%= user.email %></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p>user id: <%= user.id %></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <%= link_to "Documents", documents_path {:user_id => "#{user.id}" } , class: "btn btn-primary py-1.5 px-3"  %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like the **link_to "Documents"** to pass over the individuals user_id, so that in the index view, it only renders their documents.

```
  def index
    if current_user.admin?
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @documents = @user.documents
    else
      unless @documents = current_user.documents.where(user_id: current_user).nil?
        @documents = current_user.documents.where(user_id: current_user)
      end
    end
  end
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the way you wrote your route with `documents_path(user_id: user.id)`:

```
<%= link_to "Documents", documents_path(user_id: user.id), class: "btn btn-primary py-1.5 px-3"  %>
```

On the controller:

```
def index
  @documents = Document.where(user_id: params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
  # more logic
end
```

You don't need to test for nil because if you don't have documents for the selected user, the query will return an empty structure. you might want to use `any?` with it:

```
<% if @documents.any? %>
  <!-- show table -->
<% else %>
  <strong>No documents to display</strong>
<% end %>
```

I would like to highlight that you need to decide if you can trust the user id. If you are in a multi-tenancy app, as an example, you might need to ensure you can access that user:

```
def index
  user = Account.users.find(params[:user_id])
  @documents = Document.where(user_id: user.id) if params[:user_id]
  # more logic
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, especially the highlight on trusting the user id. It worked perfectly for what I needed